# How to lock zookeeper node data using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

I need to create a spring boot rest API from which I can get data(custom integer ID) from a node, increment it and again update it to the same node.

I am using this into a distributed environment so I need to lock the node before getting it so some other client will not update it before the current client is done.

I have implemented it using `InterProcessSemaphoreMutex` using Apache Curator but in the non-springboot environment.

I am successful in creating connections, getting data, and setting data, but not getting any useful resource for creating a lock on the node.